# What genre is "Dragonborn" by Jeremy Soule?

Tags: genre

I really like this song, and would absolutely love to listen to songs like this when trying to read.

I would sort of call it "classical", but I don't know how to distinguish the punchy nature of it. The music feels powerful, and the use of human voice more guttural (rather than traditional "soft" choir voices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choir that Jeremy Soule used had 30 people who sang in the Draconic language - that may account for the guttural tone ([source](https://www.cnet.com/news/skyrim-theme-played-on-wine-glasses-could-tame-a-dragon/)).

Jeremy's musical influences may help you find other similar songs.

- Debussy's exploration of harmony
- Wagner's grand operas
- Mozart's form and composition
- John Williams
- British pop and rock music

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Soule))

These artists are similar to Jeremy Soule, because of their John Williams influence ([source](https://www.allmusic.com/artist/jeremy-soule-mn0002596970/related)):

- Rik Schaffer
- Nobuo Uematsu
- Harry Gregson-Williams
- Valve Studio Orchestra
- Ari Pulkkinen
- audiomachine
- Inon Zur
- Thomas Bergersen
- Toby Fox
- Atlus Sound Team
- Joe Hisaishi
- Lena Raine
- Steve Jablonsky
- Trevor Morris